# Crop out image margin in base64

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner php programmer.
I have upload image system in my project. It's written in Laravel 8.

i have this code:

```
$imageInBase64 = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KYq6hP//5zzmAc/DBB5f2XYxR/hpl06IVmU3FuqJaTZHJUSyf0GuUsosATVS3KW8xRsyTFOXlIuOnKJ0XfWr.......=';
```

I need cut 100px from left site my image.

Full code base64 with my image is here: https://paste-bin.xyz/25692

How can I make it?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this directly from the Base64 unless you resize the image and then encode it. You could use CSS though to cut off 100px from the side.

Comment: In css? Can you give me sample? I have <img src='my base64code'>

Comment: Target the < img /> tag you are using to display this base64 and apply this css to it.  ```position:absolute; clip:rect(0, 0, 100px, 0);```